# Add an alphanumeric character in a timestamp

Tags: timestamp, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mule4, writefile

When writing to a csv file, how would i format the timestamp to include an alpha character 'T' like yyyy-MM-ddThh-mm-ss?

I have this in the path:

```
'File_Name_' ++ ( now() as String {format:'yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss'} ) ++ '.csv'
```

Above will produce `File_Name_2022-10-25-13-22-01.csv`

I need instead: `File_Name_2022-10-25T13-22-01.csv`

Comment: The question is really related to Mule 4 and DataWeave, which is the expression language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
now() as String {format:"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh-mm-ss"}
```

Be careful of how you mix single quotes and double quotes. If you edit in the graphical view Studio will escape the quotes for you. In the XML view you need to do that yourself.

Comment: Please mark the question as accepted and optionally upvote it, to signal to other users that the answer was useful.