# Date conversion in Mule

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am getting the date as below

```
2022-10-25 11:00:00
```

which I need to convert to

```
2022-10-25T11:00:00
```

Please let me know the appropriate data weave to achieve the above output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add an alphanumeric character in a timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74213065/add-an-alphanumeric-character-in-a-timestamp). The same format that you need is described in that answer.

Answer (score 0):

@subhash,

you can try adding the letter "T" to the input string and then convert the whole string into DateTime as shown below.

### *%dw 2.0
output application/json

(payload  replace " " with "T") as DateTime*

Answer (score 0):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var data = "2022-10-25 11:00:00"
---
data replace  " " with "T"
```